# Metamask connecting to private blockchain using custom RPC but balance not updating

Tags: blockchain, geth, metamask

I am running a private blockchain on some server. When I tried to connect the Metamask using custom RPC , its connected but unabe to update the balance. whereas on geth console I can see this error.

> "warn[] served: eth_getBalance err:'missing value for required argument2' " .